# $f(A)v=f(\lambda)v$, polynomial of eigenvalues, proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

> 7.Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, and let $A:V\to V$ be a linear map. Let $v\in V$ be an eigenvector of $A$, say $Av=\lambda v$. If $f$ is a polynomial in $K[t]$, show that $f(A)v=f(\lambda)v$.***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang.***

It is true that $A-\lambda I=0$, so that $f(A-\lambda I)=0$,since $f(A-\lambda I)=a_n(A-\lambda I)+...+a_0 (I-I)=0$. However I cannot prove that $f(A)-f(\lambda I)=0\implies f(A)=f(\lambda I)$. I tried to use the following theorem:

> Theorem: Let $f,g$ be polynomials such that $f(t)=g(t)$ for all $t\in K$. Write
>
> $f(t)=a_nt^n+...+a_0\\g(t)=b_nt^n+...+b_0$
>
> Then $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$.

Since its proof lies on the limit:

However the theorem assumes already that $f(t)=g(t)$, and the fact t is common to both polynomials certainly does not imply its equality.

***Questions***:

How can I prove the statement? Which theorem do I need? Can someone provide me a proof?

Thanks in advance|

Comment: use $A^nv=\lambda ^n v$

Comment: It is not true that $A-\lambda I=0$. It is true that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: To prove that $$f(A)-f(\lambda I)=0\implies f(A)=f(\lambda I)$$ simply take the first equation and add $f(\lambda I)$ to both sides.

Comment: Moreover, it is **by far** not true that $f(A-\lambda I)=f(A)-f(\lambda I)$. Since when does $(x+y)^5=x^5+y^5$?

Comment: I must be missing something why can't you just write out everything on the LHS explicitly?

Comment: Just to point out your misunderstanding: the thing you want to prove is not related to the theorem you are quoting. The theorem you quote asserts equality between formal polynomials, while the one you want to prove is an equality between linear transformations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes things are easy: For $f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kt^k$ we have
$$f(A)v=\Big(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kA^k\Big)v=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k A^k v=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\lambda^k v=\Big(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\lambda^k\Big)v=f(\lambda)v$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(t)=a_nt^n+\ldots+a_0$ where $a_i\in K$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Do you remember how $f(A)$ is defined for $A\in K^{n\times n}$?

> $$f(A)=a_nA^n+\ldots+a_0I$$

Now consider what $f(A)v$ is for an eigenvector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. You get

> $$f(A)v=\left(a_nA^n+\ldots+a_0I\right)v=a_nA^nv+\ldots a_0Iv.$$

Now you can use $Av=\lambda v$ to change $A$ to $\lambda$. Consider $A^nv=\lambda^n v$ since $$A^nv=A^{n-1}Av=A^{n-1}\lambda v=\lambda A^{n-1}v=\lambda A^{n-2}Av=\ldots=\lambda^2A^{n-2}v=\ldots=\lambda^nv$$and you get

> $$f(A)v=\ldots=a_n\lambda^nv+\ldots+a_0v=\left(a_n\lambda^n+\ldots+a_0\right)v=f(\lambda)v.$$

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(A) = c_0 + c_1A + c_2A^2 + \dots c_nA^n$, then $f(A)$ acting on $v$ yields $V$ as a $K[x]$ module.

For your question,

\begin{align}
f(A)v &= (c_0 + c_1A + c_2A^2 + \dots c_nA^n)(v)\\ &= c_0 + c_1Av + c_2A^2v + \dots c_nA^nv\\
&=c_0 + c_1\lambda v + c_2A(\lambda v) + \dots c_nA^{n-1}(\lambda v) \quad \text{recall $A\lambda =  \lambda A$}\\ 
&=c_0 + c_1\lambda v + c_2(\lambda^2 v) + \dots c_n(\lambda^n v) \\
&=(c_0 + c_1\lambda  + c_2\lambda^2  + \dots c_n\lambda^n)(v)\\
&=f(\lambda)v
\end{align}